# Value for return when not specifying what to return

Tags: objective-c

If I have some code like below, and I use `return`, what is really being returned? Is this assuming self? Or Void or what?

```
if (actSheet) {
    [actSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that at this point the function exits. It is allowed in void functions. e.g. it does not return any value.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is being returned. If you want to get down to absolute basics, most compilers will use a register to either contain or point to the value being returned. But for a void function, the value of the register is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I've always assumed it was returning void, as presumably the method is -(void)someMethod